# Tabby JS with SVG Prevent Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, tabs

I am trying to use the [Tabby JS Plugin](https://github.com/cferdinandi/tabby) with an inline SVG element. Clicking anchor tags outside of SVG works perfectly, when wrapped around SVG elements, the page 'jumps' to the ID.

Can anyone out there provide an explanation for why this happens?

https://github.com/cferdinandi/tabby

I have created a [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pxJNZZ) using the original plugin HTML where you can see this issue.

```
<g data-tabs>
        <a data-tab href="#tab1">
      <rect id="red" x="177.9" y="44.2" class="tab st1" width="96" height="77.5"/>
    </a>
        <a data-tab href="#tab2">
      <rect id="orange" x="107.9" y="169.8" class="tab st2" width="166" height="101.5"/>
    </a>
</g>
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is happening as you are using **tabby** to show your HTML elements in tabs while for SVG elements you have used **`#`** **(Location Hash)** to navigate to a page element. Location hash will make the control jump to the element specified. This is the behaviour that you are are noticing.

You can read the below blogs to get a good idea as to how the Location hash navigation happens.

**W3 School Documentation:** https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

**Blog Explaining Navigation:** https://www.oshyn.com/Blogs/2011/December/JavaScript_Navigation_using_Hash_Change____